# Websocket net::ERR_SSL_OBSOLETE_VERSION Error in Chrome

Tags: c#, websocket, tls1.2

I am getting the following error message when trying to connect to an "wss" WebSocket connection string in Chrome that is not happening in Firefox Or IE.

Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_OBSOLETE_VERSION

I have enabled TLS 1.2 on my server but I get the same error again.

I tried many C # components for Web Socket Server such as: SuperWebSocket, WebSocketSharp and TCPListener
but either the TLS version cannot be adjusted or it is not optimal.

Please anyone who has solved this problem with any component guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try with websocket-sharp and

serverSsl.SslConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;

Comment: I have used this before but it did not solve my problem